# Why is this script not changing directory

Tags: bash, scripting

Ok simple bash script question - don't laugh.
My script just changes directory:

```
echo on;
echo "running script";
CURRENT_DIR=.;
cd ..;
pwd;
```

I can see it change directory in the echo but when it finishes it, my terminal is still at the same directory. Any tips?

Comment: FYI the terminating semicolons (`;`) are not required in the script. The semicolon is a command separator if you want to put several commands on the same line.

Comment: Not your question, but maybe good to know: "CURRENT_DIR=." does not store the current directory name, it just stores the dot itself. If you want to store the current directory e.g. in order to return to it later, do "CURRENT_DIR=$PWD".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run a `bash` script, it runs in its own shell. That means that it has it's own shell environment including what the current working directory is. If you `cd` within the script, that script will be operating in that new current directory. But when it's completed, you are still at the current directory that your user-level shell is at since a subshell doesn't touch it.

If you want to impact the current shell environment, one way is to execute it with `.`:

```
. my_script
```

This is like running `sh my_script` but operates within the environment of your current user shell.